fanotify does not notify changes in /run
I want to get fanotify to get added\modified files from entire file system.
Based on GNU examples, I have come up with following code.
I am running this code on Oracle Enterprise Linux 9.
There are two problems with this code:

I do not get get events for created\modified files in "/run"
Perhaps I need separate question for this: I was under impression that FAN_EVENT_NEXT would be blocking. But it doesn't seem to be. Because of that I have to put sleep(1)

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/fanotify.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

const static int _INIT_FLAGS = FAN_CLOEXEC | FAN_NONBLOCK | FAN_UNLIMITED_QUEUE | FAN_UNLIMITED_MARKS | FAN_CLASS_CONTENT;
const static int _INIT_FID_FLAGS = FAN_REPORT_FID | FAN_REPORT_DFID_NAME;
const static int INIT_FID_FLAGS = FAN_CLOEXEC | FAN_NONBLOCK | FAN_UNLIMITED_QUEUE | FAN_UNLIMITED_MARKS | FAN_REPORT_FID | FAN_REPORT_DFID_NAME;


static volatile int keepRunning = 1;


void intHandler(int dummy) {
    printf("flaggin..\n");
    keepRunning = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fan;
    ssize_t len, path_len;
    int mount_fd, event_fd;
    char buf[4096];
    char fdpath[32];
    char path[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char procfd_path[PATH_MAX];
    struct file_handle *file_handle;
    char full_path[(PATH_MAX * 2)+ 1];

    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);

    ssize_t buflen, linklen;
    struct fanotify_event_metadata *metadata;
    struct fanotify_event_info_fid *fid;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s /dir\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    mount_fd = open(argv[1], O_DIRECTORY | O_RDONLY);
    if (mount_fd == -1) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //fan = fanotify_init(FAN_CLASS_NOTIF | FAN_REPORT_FID, O_RDWR);
    fan = fanotify_init(INIT_FID_FLAGS, O_RDWR);
    if(fan == -1) {
        perror("fanotify_init");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int ret = fanotify_mark(fan,
                            FAN_MARK_ADD | FAN_MARK_FILESYSTEM,
                            FAN_CREATE | FAN_MODIFY /*| FAN_DELETE | FAN_EVENT_ON_CHILD*/,
                            mount_fd, //AT_FDCWD,
                            argv[1]
                            );
    if(ret == -1) {
        perror("fanotify_mark");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1) {
        if (0 == keepRunning) {
            break;
        }

        buflen = read(fan, buf, sizeof(buf));
        metadata = (struct fanotify_event_metadata*)&buf;
        for (; FAN_EVENT_OK(metadata, buflen); metadata = FAN_EVENT_NEXT(metadata, buflen)) {
            if (0 == keepRunning) {
                break;
            }
            fid = (struct fanotify_event_info_fid *) (metadata + 1);
            file_handle = (struct file_handle *) fid->handle;

            /* Ensure that the event info is of the correct type */

            const char* file_name = NULL;

            if (fid->hdr.info_type != FAN_EVENT_INFO_TYPE_DFID_NAME) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Received unexpected event info type, ignoring..: %d\n", fid->hdr.info_type);
                continue;
            }


           file_name = file_handle->f_handle +
                       file_handle->handle_bytes;


           event_fd = open_by_handle_at(mount_fd, file_handle, O_RDONLY);
           if (event_fd == -1) {
               if (errno == ESTALE) {
                   printf("File handle is no longer valid. "
                           "File has been deleted\n");
                   continue;
               } else {
                   perror("open_by_handle_at");
                   //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                   continue;
               }
           }

           snprintf(procfd_path, sizeof(procfd_path), "/proc/self/fd/%d",
                   event_fd);

           /* Retrieve and print the path of the modified dentry. */

           path_len = readlink(procfd_path, path, sizeof(path) - 1);
           if (path_len == -1) {
               perror("readlink");
               //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               continue;
           }
           path[path_len] = '\0';

    
           if (NULL != file_name) {
              printf("Path: %s file_name: %s\n", path, file_name);
           }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}


I have tried combination of flags to fanotify_mark without any success.
Thanks in advance!
